# Regular expression print only the first character

Tags: python, regex

Instead of printing whole "final' sentence It is printing only "p". Can anyone help here?

```
final = r'print "\n^^^###***===TP test result: $final_verdict===***###^^^\n";'
searchObj = re.compile(r'[\w\s\"\n\^\^\^\#\#\#\*\*\*\=\=\=\w+\s\w+\:\s\$\w+\=\=\=\#\#\#\*\*\*\^\^\^\n\"\;]')
print(searchObj)
y=searchObj.match(final)
if y:
    print("Found",y.group())
else:
    print("Nothing")
```

Result:

```
re.compile('[\\w\\s\\"\\n\\^\\^\\^\\#\\#\\#\\*\\*\\*\\=\\=\\=\\w+\\s\\w+\\:\\s\\$\\w+\\=\\=\\=\\#\\#\\#\\*\\*\\*\\^\\^\\^\\n\\"\\;]')
```

Found p

Comment: your range only matches 1 character. Consider adding `+` after the closing bracket... also consider raw prefix to avoid doubling the backslashes...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I think his intent was not to define a character group at all.

Answer (score 2):

You've put square brackets over your regex, this means you defined a *character group*, you should remove these:

```
r'\w\s\"\n\^\^\^\#\#\#\*\*\*\=\=\=\w+\s\w+\:\s\$\w+\=\=\=\#\#\#\*\*\*\^\^\^\n\"\;'
```

By using a character group you say: any of the characters between the square brackets. So `[ab]` means: *`a` or `b`*, not *`a` followed by `b`*.

Now however your string does not match anymore (it is of course harder to match a sequence than a single character). You can however improve it to:

```
r'\w\s\"\\n\^\^\^###\*\*\*===\w+\s\w+\s\w+:\s\$\w+===\*\*\*###\^\^\^\\n\";'
#       ^        ^^^      ^^^        ^^^^^        ^^^      ^^^      ^
```

The carrets on the second line show the changes. First of all you do not need to escape `#` and `=`, furthermore you specify `\n` which Python sees as a new line character, but you want to match `\n` (two characters), so you need to escape the backslash, so `\\n`; finally you forgot that there are three words before the colon (`:`).

You can test and modify your regex with this [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/c7mJSo/1).

Comment: you don't need to escape the `#` and `:` and `=` chars. It makes a clearer expression...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: well the OP forgot to escape `\` as well, so the regex does not match, I'm working on an improved version.

Comment: regex101 helped to solve this issue. Thank you all for the response.